# Liquibase 3.8 inserts tinyint value with quotes

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am trying to insert a value into mysql using a liquibase script:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase" id="6225">
    <insert tableName="master">
        <column name="id" value="7"/>
        <column name="insightname" value="topic_modelling"/>
        <column name="insighttype" value="1" valueBoolean="true"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

But when I try this it gives me the error:

> Error: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'insighttype' at row
>   1 [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO db.master (id,
>   insightname, insighttype) VALUES ('7', 'topic_modelling', '1')]

Is it because the value are passed with quotes? What is the solution?

My Create table statement looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE ss_insightmaster (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  insightname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  enabled tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: can you include `SHOW CREATE TABLE db.master` to be sure we're understanding the types right?

Comment: @danblack - added CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Database handles Boolean values differently - Liquibase is expecting the `insighttype` of type `BIT` not `TINYINT` since you are using MySQL as you can see in the liquibase [github](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/31a22561423919b3875e0563a7bdcde3b9e457a9/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/BooleanType.java).

**OR**

As a dirty hack you can run the changeset with another `dbms` where a `NUMBER`is expected:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase" id="6225" dbms="oracle">
    <insert tableName="master">
        <column name="id" value="7"/>
        <column name="insightname" value="topic_modelling"/>
        <column name="insighttype" value="1" valueBoolean="true"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```